# Flutter How to resolve type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<SubscriptionPackageDetails>?' error

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-hive

I am new to flutter and getting below error while parsing data.

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<SubscriptionPackageDetails>?'
```

I have SubscriptionPackageDetails class and in response I am getting List< SubscriptionPackageDetails>. Right now I am getting an empty array of SubscriptionPackageDetails and getting error.

If the array has data then it work perfectly.

I am using below logic for parsing

```
subscriptionDetails: List.unmodifiable(
      (data[ApiExchangeKeys.subscriptionDetails] as List<dynamic>).map(
          (package) => SubscriptionPackageDetails.fromJson(
              package as Map<String, dynamic>))),
```

Comment: What do you exact want explain in brief

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I am getting mentioned exception if response array is an empty. I want to resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
subscriptionDetails: List<SubscriptionPackageDetails>.from(
            data[ApiExchangeKeys.subscriptionDetails].map((x) => 
         SubscriptionPackageDetails.fromJson(x)))
```